# Android background services (like Viber)

Tags: android, service, background

I am developing a little VoIP application and i need to stay connected to the server.

A was using push notifications at first (to wake up the device on incoming call), but android push notifications are not reliable due to very long heartbeat interval.

The second solution was to use a service with `startForeground()`. This method works, but leaves an icon in the notification bar (i know it's the way it should be, but please read on).

If i don't use `startForeground()` then service falls asleep as soon as te phone sleeps.

TLDR:
Viber has a background service without `startForeground()` but it still works if the phone is sleeping and accepts incoming calls (even with push notifications disabled). How did they do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose they hold a permanent TCP connection and use `AlarmManager` to wake up the phone with some interval (let's say 5 minutes) and keep the connection alive.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534732/how-to-make-the-android-device-hold-a-tcp-connection-to-internet-without-wake-lo).

Comment: So basically this answer led me to the right direction! Anyone interested, you can check the discussion in the link from this answer.

Comment: But you get messages instantly, not after 5 minutes passed

Answer (score 0):

Try using WakeLock to keep device always awake. But it may cause battery drain.