# How does TCP connection works on Android?

Tags: java, android, tcp, smack

I am using smack for building a chat app in Android. I am using a sticky_service to hold the connection. I have a confusion that if my app goes  to sleep what happens to TCP connection. I have read few answers on the page - [How to make the Android device hold a TCP connection to Internet without wake lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534732/how-to-make-the-android-device-hold-a-tcp-connection-to-internet-without-wake-lo)

It wakes up for a brief period of time - For smack I can think of it as the processmessage listener (http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener) is called. I am inserting data in db for that. Is there any guarantee that work will be complete or if the execution is left in between will it be started from there.

Answer (score 0):

Hello dear you can use this code snippet :

```
protected void connect() {
    Log.d(Config.LOGTAG, account.getJid().toBareJid().toString() + ": connecting");
    features.encryptionEnabled = false;
    lastConnect = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    lastPingSent = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    this.attempt++;
    try {
        shouldAuthenticate = shouldBind = !account.isOptionSet(Account.OPTION_REGISTER);
        tagReader = new XmlReader(wakeLock);
        tagWriter = new TagWriter();
        packetCallbacks.clear();
        this.changeStatus(Account.State.CONNECTING);
        final Bundle result = DNSHelper.getSRVRecord(account.getServer());
        final ArrayList<Parcelable> values = result.getParcelableArrayList("values");
        if ("timeout".equals(result.getString("error"))) {
            throw new IOException("timeout in dns");
        } else if (values != null) {
            int i = 0;
            boolean socketError = true;
            while (socketError && values.size() > i) {
                final Bundle namePort = (Bundle) values.get(i);
                try {
                    String srvRecordServer;
                    try {
                        srvRecordServer = IDN.toASCII(namePort.getString("name"));
                    } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO: Handle me?`
                        srvRecordServer = "";
                    }
                    final int srvRecordPort = namePort.getInt("port");
                    final String srvIpServer = namePort.getString("ip");
                    final InetSocketAddress addr;
                    if (srvIpServer != null) {
                        addr = new InetSocketAddress(srvIpServer, srvRecordPort);
                        Log.d(Config.LOGTAG, account.getJid().toBareJid().toString()
                                + ": using values from dns " + srvRecordServer
                                + "[" + srvIpServer + "]:" + srvRecordPort);
                    } else {
                        addr = new InetSocketAddress(srvRecordServer, srvRecordPort);
                        Log.d(Config.LOGTAG, account.getJid().toBareJid().toString()
                                + ": using values from dns "
                                + srvRecordServer + ":" + srvRecordPort);
                    }
                    socket = new Socket();
                    socket.connect(addr, 20000);
                    socketError = false;
                } catch (final UnknownHostException e) {
                    Log.d(Config.LOGTAG, account.getJid().toBareJid().toString() + ": " + e.getMessage());
                    i++;
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.d(Config.LOGTAG, account.getJid().toBareJid().toString() + ": " + e.getMessage());
                    i++;
                }
            }
            if (socketError) {
                throw new UnknownHostException();
            }
        } else if (result.containsKey("error")
                && "nosrv".equals(result.getString("error", null))) {


             //todo:change here to server.


 socket = new Socket(server_ip, server port);

    } else {
        throw new IOException("timeout in dns");
    }
    final OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
    tagWriter.setOutputStream(out);
    final InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
    tagReader.setInputStream(in);
    tagWriter.beginDocument();
    sendStartStream();
    Tag nextTag;
    while ((nextTag = tagReader.readTag()) != null) {
        if (nextTag.isStart("stream")) {
            processStream(nextTag);
            break;
        } else {
            throw new IOException("unknown tag on connect");
        }
    }
    if (socket.isConnected()) {
        socket.close();
    }
} catch (final UnknownHostException | ConnectException e) {
    this.changeStatus(Account.State.SERVER_NOT_FOUND);
} catch (final IOException | XmlPullParserException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    Log.d(Config.LOGTAG, account.getJid().toBareJid().toString() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    this.changeStatus(Account.State.OFFLINE);
} finally {
    if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {


          try {
                wakeLock.release();
            } catch (final RuntimeException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

enjoy your code:)